# How to pass arguments from views to node.tpl.php

Tags: views, 6, theming

Is there a way to pass arguments from views to a node template other than via selecting build modes? I use node as row style.

I used display suite + node displays to set up a custom build mode. In my node-"content type".tpl.php I then can decide via

```
$node->build_mode
```

what to render.

But first I feels like way over the top to install display suite + node displays just to pass one argument and second I ran into problems with this configuration. Everything looks fine in view's preview but after saving the view I got a "merory size exhausted" error.

So when there's time I try to reproduce this with a clean install an file a bug but at the moment I would be happy to know if there's another way to pass parameters from views to my node templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it. There's the [Build modes](http://drupal.org/project/buildmodes) module that does exactly what I want and only that.